# Windows Phone Multi Line Text Box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, telerik

I want to create a UI element that behaves approximately like the native WP SMS App's input text box.

Basically it should

- start as a single line text box
- when my text reaches the end of the first line, it should expand one line to encompass it
- this needs to go to a Max Height of 5 line (where a line = the text box's Height value)
- once my text requires more than 5 lines, the text box should stop expanding and a vertical scroll bar should appear

Any suggestions on how I can do this? I'd rather not use events to see how much text I've entered and expand/compress the text box based on that, or create a new UI element from scratch.

If it helps, I've got access to Telerik's RAD Controls for Windows Phone (RadTextBox).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you attempted making use of the [FrameworkElement.MaxHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxheight(v=vs.95).aspx) property? The markup would be similar to:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxHeight="200" />
```

The given value for max height is simply an example and may not meet your specific needs.

Note: As mentioned in the comments below, be certain to remove any value specified for Height. The declaration will constrain the element to that height at all times.

Comment: Doesn't modify the actual height of the element - no matter how many characters I enter, the text box is still displayed as a one line text box.

Comment: @drl Be certain you don't have a value specified for Height. That will constrain the element to that height at all times. Test with a MaxHeight value of 200 as that is approximately five lines.

Comment: It worked perfectly when I took out the explicit height! It even works to shrink the text box when I'm deleting text. Seriously thank you!

Comment: @lthibodeaux: i am not able to get vertical scroll bars